# How to use the d and π array to check if the shortest path from s to t in G is unique or not, in O(n log n + m) time?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

We are given a directed graph G = (V, E) with positive weight function: w : E → R>0, and two vertices s, t ∈ V . Suppose we have already computed the d and π array using the Dijkastra’s algorithm: d[v] is the length of the shortest path from s to v, and π[v] is the vertex before v in the path.

How do we use the d and π array to check if the shortest path from s to t in
G is unique or not, in O(n log n + m) time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each edge (u->v) along the shortest path, consider all the other ways we could get to v -- that is, consider all other vertices x where there's an edge (x->v).  If `shortest_path(s to u)+|u->v|` is the same length as `shortest_path(s to x)+|x->v|` (where `|u->v|` means the length of that edge) then there is more than one shortest path to from s to t.

I think this if-statement is pretty easy to follow, but let me know if it's not.  We should also check that if the shortest path is non-unique, then this procedure will always find that out.  Intuitively, I think it's true, and if it's true, you can probably prove it by assuming the existence of a shortest-path other than the one described in π, stating that that means the second shortest-path deviates from π in at least some place, and exploring the logical conclusions of that.